# Graphics.Blit() doesn't seem to mix well with my custom shader on Android build

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a simple project in 2019.4.14f1 that works really well in the editor but doesn't when I Build & Run for Android.

I'm trying to "Paint" on a transparent Plane. To do so I used a shader that takes a Texture and prints another Texture at some Coordinates. The shader isn't applied to the Plane but I use it with 2 Blit() to Update the texture of the plane.

The error I get is that on the editor the alpha seems to be normal but on android the Plane is black and the Texture I draw doesn't have a smooth edge.

On the plane, the material I use is Unlit/Transparent and I change to _MainTex.

The Shader DrawPaint.shader :

```c
Shader "Unlit/DrawPaint"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Coordinates("BrushCoordinates", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _Color("BrushColor", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
        _SizeX("BrushSizeX", Float) = 50
        _SizeY("BrushSizeY", Float) = 50
        _BrushTex("BrushTex", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Strength("Strength", Float) = 1
    }
        SubShader
        {
            Tags {"RenderType"="Transparent" }
            LOD 100

            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert 
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma target 2.0

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex, _BrushTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                fixed4 _Color, _Coordinates;
                float _Strength, _SizeX, _SizeY;

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    half4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    half2 diff = _Coordinates.xy - i.uv;
                    half2 scaledDiff = diff * half2(_SizeX,_SizeY);
                    if (abs(scaledDiff.x) < 0.5 && abs(scaledDiff.y) < 0.5)
                    {
                        half4 texVal = tex2D(_BrushTex, scaledDiff + half2(0.5, 0.5));
                        return saturate(texVal.w > 0.01 ? _Color * texVal * _Strength + col : col);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return col;
                    }
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
}
```

And the script that is on the Plane :

```cs
public class DrawableSurface : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Shader _drawShader;

    [SerializeField]
    private Texture2D _brushTex;

    private RenderTexture _paintTex;
    private Material _mat, _drawMat;

    [SerializeField]
    private float startSize = 8f;

    private void Awake() 
    {

        _drawMat = new Material(_drawShader);
        _drawMat.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
        _drawMat.SetFloat("_SizeX", startSize);
        _drawMat.SetFloat("_SizeY", startSize);
        _drawMat.SetFloat("_Strength", 0.1f);
        _drawMat.SetTexture("_MainTex", Texture2D.whiteTexture);
        _drawMat.SetTexture("_BrushTex", _brushTex);

        _mat = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        _paintTex = new RenderTexture(1024, 1024, 0);
        _mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", _paintTex);
    }

    public void OnHit(Vector2 texCoord)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit at " + texCoord);
        _drawMat.SetVector("_Coordinates", new Vector4(texCoord.x, texCoord.y, 0, 0));
        RenderTexture tmp = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(_paintTex.width, _paintTex.height, 0);
        Graphics.Blit(_paintTex, tmp);
        Graphics.Blit(tmp, _paintTex, _drawMat);
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(tmp);
    }
}
```

Then I just raycast with `Physics.Raycast` and `screenPointToRay` and pass the `hit.texCoord`

In the editor :
[image: In the Editor everything looks perfect]

On Android :
[image: On Android, the background is black and alpha doesn't seem to be working]

If I add a texture with transparency on the plane and comment the line `_mat.SetTexture("_MainTex", _paintTex);` the transparency works (but the painting part obviously doesn't :) ) Android supports the material on the plane.

So I pin pointed the error to be on the RenderTexture and I suspect the Blit because I've read that there is problem with it on Android and adding `ZTest Always` to my shader should solve it but it doesn't change anything.
I spent my day looking for answers but couldn't find one and I need to use 2019.4 for this project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding `_paintTex.Create();` solved my problem. I stil don't get why it worked in editor but not on Android. Maybe the Render Texture are not created automatically on Android.